# Sed output a value between two matching strings in a url

Tags: bash, url, sed, grep

I have multiple urls as input

```
https://drive.google.com/a/domain.com/file/d/1OR9QLGsxiLrJIz3JAdbQRACd-G9ZfL3O/view?usp=drivesdk
https://drive.google.com/a/domain.com/file/d/1sEWMFqGW9p2qT-8VIoBesPlVJ4xvOzXD/view?usp=drivesdk
```

How can I create a sed command to simply return only the file ID

desired output:

```
1OR9QLGsxiLrJIz3JAdbQRACd-G9ZfL3O
1sEWMFqGW9p2qT-8VIoBesPlVJ4xvOzXD
```

Looks like I need to start between /d/ and stop at /view but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

I've tried? `sed -e 's/d\(.*\)\/view/\1/'`

Comment: If it's always the 8th position when delimited by a `/` then `cut` or `awk` may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this with `cut -d '/' -f 8`
also `awk -F/ '{print $8}' file` worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your command was almost right:

```
# Wrong
sed  -e 's/d\(.*\)\/view/\1/'
# better, removing unmatched stuff including the / after the d
sed  -e 's/.*d\/\(.*\)\/view.*/\1/'
# better: using # for making the command easier to read
sed  -e 's#.*d/\(.*\)/view.*#\1#'
# Alternative:Using cut when you don't know which field /d/ is
some_straem | grep -Eo '/d/.*/view' | cut -d/ -f3
```